# Add java List in JsonObject return value

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I want to add a list in the json return value. Here is my code -

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/servicearea", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String ServiceArea(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    {

        List<ServiceArea> serviceLists = locationService.getAllServiceArea();

        JsonObject result = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("message", "test")
                .add("serviceLists", serviceLists)
                .build();

        return result.toString();
    }
```

'serviceLists' is the one that I want to add. I'm getting error in this line - .add("serviceLists", serviceLists). Error message is that JsonObjectBuilder is not applicable for the arguments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, there is no such a method overload. Try to convert your `serviceLists` to `JsonArrayBuilder` first (not sure if it's the best match, but it sounds it is).

Comment: why can't you just create a Pojo and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a pojo like this

```
class ReturnPojo {
    private String message;
    private List<ServiceArea> serviceLists;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And from your controller you can do

```
ReturnPojo returnPojo = new ReturnPojo;
returnPojo.setMessage("test");
returnPojo.setServiceLists(serviceLists);

return returnPojo;
```

Change the method signature to return `ReturnPojo`

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is only useful if you are using Rest API and Spring.

create class ServiceListPojo:

```
public class ServiceListPOJO{
List<ServiceArea> serviceLists;

public void setServiceLists(List<ServiceArea> serviceLists){
this.serviceLists = serviceLists;
}
}
```

Annotate your controller with `@RestController`

```
@RestController
public class SomeController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/servicearea")
    public ServiceListPOJO ServiceArea()
    {
        List<ServiceArea> serviceLists = locationService.getAllServiceArea();
        ServiceListPOJO slp = new ServiceListPOJO();
       slp.setServciceLists(serviceLists);
       return slp;
    }
}
```